# MakeFeatureLayer_management parsing error (for loop)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcmap

I want to make a Feature Layer for each month in the table "Sightings1995-2014".

Why doesn't it work?

> > > for month in range (01,12):                                                            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Sightings1995-2014", "test%s" %month,"DATE >= date'01.%s.1995' AND DATE < date'01.%s.2014'" % (month, month+1)

Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 1)

for the output in each year this code worked

> > > for year in range(1995,2014): 
> > >       arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management
> > >       ("Sightings1995-2014", "test%s" % year, "DATE >= date'01.01.%s' AND DATE < date'01.01.%s'" % (year, year+1))

Comment: now python makes the FeatureLayer but does not put each month into a FeatureLayer. Instead he puts the hole "database" ("Sightings1995-2014") into each feature Layer -> so 12 Feature Layer with the hole database in it.

Comment: Rather than tacking another question on as a comment I think you should research/ask it separately as per the [Tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for month in range (01,12):
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Sightings1995-2014", "test%s" %month,"DATE >= date'01.%s.1995' AND DATE < date'01.%s.2014'" % (month, month+1)
```

When you did it for `year` you ended your `for` statement with a colon (:), but when you did it for `month` that was omitted.

Comment: yeah that was the problem :D sometimes you didn't see mistakes like that.